# Access OAuthd Open Source Library on Localhost

Tags: node.js

```
OAuth daemon
```

oauthd is the open source version of the OAuth.io core. This is a background api server that runs on your own server that allow your clients to authenticate to any available provider.

Prerequisites

A working redis database >= v2.4, check Redis quickstart for a properly installation
nodejs >= v0.8.2
npm >= v1.1

After above steps i run these commands

```
1) npm install -g coffee-script grunt grunt-cli forever
2) npm install oauthd
3) npm [start|stop|restart] option to start server but its not working 

Actually i want setup this library on localhost but its not working please any one can       help me in it
```

Insctuctions Followed from this link
    https://oauth.io/docs/oauthd

thanks

Comment: By default, it's running on localhost. What system do you have? What error do you get? it's not clear in your question

Comment: I am installing it on window 7 but its not working. its giving me error that is   ( gyp build error ) when i run this command ( npm install ).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also have python installed.  A gyp build error sounds like the node-gyp library cannot find a python.  On most unix platforms this is not a problem.  On Windows you may need to install python.   Here is the pyathon node_module with more details instruction on getting that package installed: https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-gyp